# jQuery Not Setting CSS Cursor Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to use jQuery so I can make the cursor a pointer but it doesn't work.  Basically jQuery doesn't work and I don't know what to do because I really tried everything and checked twice.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ShowMeHowMainPageCSS.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "Parts" id = "part1">News Feed</div>
<div class = "Parts" id = "part2">Blog</div>
<div class = "Parts" id = "part3">Video</div>
<div class = "Parts" id = "part4">My Profile</div>
<div id = "menu">
    <div id = "newsFeedMenu" class = "circle"></div>
    <div id = "BlogMenu" class = "circle"></div>
    <div id = "videoToturialsMenu" class = "circle"></div>
    <div id = "MyProfileMenu" class = "circle"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

$('.circle').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    $('#menu').css('opacity','1');
});

});
</script>

<script type ="text/javascript" src = "jQueryF.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "showMeHowJQUERY.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add that script block after the jquery library inclusion script tag..

Comment: Why would you use JQuery to set CSS instead of just setting it in CSS?

Comment: If you look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) you'll see the error messages, which will help the next time a script doesn't work.

Comment: it doesnt metter ,actualy i need to do something else but i thought maby i wrote a wrong code or something so i wrote something simple just to see if jQuery even works but its not responding

Comment: umm i need to use jQuery as a different document not in the html ' so you were right putting the code after the scripts did solve the problem but if use other document it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

you need to load the javascript file first before you define anything using them

put this as the top of your code inside the head tag

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "jQueryF.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src = "showMeHowJQUERY.js"></script>
```